# Avoid EF update the null image to database in .Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, null, edit, httppostedfilebase

In my `SachController`, there is an Edit method like below. In the view, there are several `textbox` and one `file-input` for upload `image` object. Sometime, user doesn't want to change the image and they just don't select a new image. And the `image` (`HttpPostedFileBase`) is null.

How can I avoid the null image but still use short update like this:

```
            [HttpPost]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "MaSach,NhanDe,MaDM,MaNXB,NamXB,GiaBia,PhanTramGiamGia,TrongLuong,MaBV,MaBia,Dai,Rong,Cao")] Sach sach, HttpPostedFileBase image)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    uploadImage(sach, image);
                    db.Entry(sach).State = EntityState.Modified;                
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                ViewBag.MaBV = new SelectList(db.BaiViet, "MaBV", "NhanDe", sach.MaBV);
                ViewBag.MaBia = new SelectList(db.Bia, "MaBia", "TenBia", sach.MaBia);
                ViewBag.MaNXB = new SelectList(db.NhaXuatBan, "MaNXB", "Ten", sach.MaNXB);
                return View(sach);
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark Image property as not modified:

```
db.Entry(sach).State = EntityState.Modified;
if (image == null)
   db.Entry(sach).Property(m => m.Image).IsModified = false;
db.SaveChanges();
```